# how to share same value across multiple view in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to share user details across multiple views in flutter. This is my home Screen, now I need username on my profile Screen also so, do I have to right all this code ***initState()*** again or is there any way to store values in global variable so that I can use where ever I want.

```
Map<String, Object>userName = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object>loginDetails = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserMeta();
  }

  getUserMeta() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    loginDetails = jsonDecode(prefs.get("loggedDetails"));
    userName  = loginDetails["user"];
  }

Widget profileAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.0,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffefebfb),
      floating: false,
      pinned: true,
      centerTitle: false,
      title: Text(
        "${userName["name"]}",
        style: TextStyle(
          //fontSize: 24,
          fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor * 24,
          //color: Colors.deepOrange[700],
          color: Color(0xff5b1dd6),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ).... so on,
```

Answer (score 1):

You should study about state management and data injection in flutter and where to place data logic of your app in summery you can use something like a block or provider libraries and in your Application class which is the class you are giving it to runApp() function initiate your data and in the child widget class use the provider or bloc to access the data in the parent which is the App class flutter uses tree hierarchy in the application so the App class is the parent of all widgets and you can access the app widget and all the fields and properties that you have stored there in the child widgets whit help of Provider, Block, InheritedWidget or some other tools ...